# How to get an auto-reset event's state with C++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, events

Say, if I created an event like so:

```
HANDLE hGlobalEvent = ::CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
```

Is it possible to get its state by its handle w/o changing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't any direct way to do that. Even if there were a way to query an event object, the answer might change at any time, making the information immediately out of date.

Comment: Oh, I see. The race condition, hah?

Comment: "No, there isn't any direct way to do that." - actually there is a way. You can use `WaitForSingleObject(hGlobalEvent, 0)`.  But yes, there would be a race condition between the time the result is obtained and the time the result is acted on if the state of the event is changed by another thread.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: But using `WaitForSingleObject()` on an auto-reset event changes the state from Set to Reset.